# Getting Data to add correctly from ASP.Net to XML so it displays correctly in Grid view

Tags: asp.net, xml, webforms

Soo relatively new here and having a tad bit of an issue with my coding:

Here's what i got so far to work with:

```
PurchaseCollection>
  <purchases CustomerId="1" fullName="Jareth Baxter" 
emailAddress="jareth.baxter@gmail.com" productName="Product 1" 
unitPrice="12.50" quantity="5" />
```

Now this works perfectly for my grid view, however I cannot for the life of me get the add record to action the record in the same way

So basically, the above displays as a grid view on the main ASP.Net form I've built - However I need to make a second form that adds the data accordingly to the XML sheet in question.

Here's a snippet code I tried, but didn't work as intended.

```
XmlDocument XmlDocObj = new XmlDocument();
        XmlDocObj.Load(Server.MapPath("/Data/purchases.xml"));
        XmlNode RootNode = 
XmlDocObj.SelectSingleNode("PurchaseCollection");
PurchasesNode.AppendChild(XmlDocObj.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, 
"fullName", "")).InnerText = fullName.Text;
 RootNode.AppendChild(XmlDocObj.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, 
"emailAddress", "")).InnerText = emailAddress.Text;
    RootNode.AppendChild(XmlDocObj.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "productName", "")).InnerText = productName.Text;
    RootNode.AppendChild(XmlDocObj.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "unitPrice", "")).InnerText = unitPrice.Text;
    RootNode.AppendChild(XmlDocObj.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "quantity", "")).InnerText = quantity.Text;
    XmlDocObj.Save(Server.MapPath("/Data/purchases.xml"));
```

Any advice would be awesome! (Please note: I'm not asking to be led on a tangent of .js or SQL as this is for a uni assignment, however i'm stuck on where i can word this one)

Essentially the outcome should look like this:
[Main Index page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bu6hM.png)
HOWEVER: when it works - the code ends up create new block of xml code instead of attributed group

Comment: What output do you get when you run it? I'm wondering if you might be missing the `<purchases ...` node in that code. I feel like you need to add that. Here is a ref that might be handy: https://csharp.net-tutorials.com/xml/writing-xml-with-the-xmldocument-class/

Comment: Close my friend and the article is indeed helpful. However what I am aiming for is a gridveiw data:

I'd attach a screenshot of the output, however I cannot in the comments. I'll add it to the main body